# if the type of instances is simply 'instance', how does Python know these are instances of the foo class?

Tags: python, object, object-type

Is putting objects in a list (in python) just like putting class object in `ArrayList<object>` ??
I tried this code

```
class foo():
    def __init__(self):
        self.name = "frank"
        self.id = 007


obj1 = foo()
obj2 = foo()

element_list = []
element_list.append(obj1)
element_list.append(obj2)

for element in element_list:
    print(type(element))
    print(element.name)
```

The object type turned out to be `<type 'instance'>`. But then the object correctly printed the variable assigned.

How does python identify the type of these instances? Even if it is getting an instance object, how is it able to map the class?

Comment: I don't believe you. For starters, this isn't even valid code.

Comment: What Python version are you using? I could imagine a very old Python returning the "instance" type, but not any remotely recent version.

Comment: Python lists just hold references to arbitrary objects, they aren't typed. I would expect `type(element)` to give you e.g. `<class '__main__.foo'>` - of course instances "know" what class they are. You only get `<type 'instance'>` if you *don't* inherit `object` in 2.x.

Comment: Python is strongly typed and the interpreter keeps track of all variables types.  Python lists don't care what type of objects are contained inside, they can be inhomogeneous.

Comment: ya sorry for this code my original class does not inherit object !! but still works in the same fashion as above, i cannot put actual code as it is not mine. but the way it is used is same as above

Comment: @shubham: your question appears to be *if the type of instances is simply `'instance'`, how does Python know these are instances of the `foo` class?* Is that a better description of your problem?

Comment: @martin - yes exactly !! thanks for putting it up simply. sorry for my crude language

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`type()` does not work correctly for instances of old-style classes (Python 2 classes that do not inherit from `object`). Python looks at the `.__class__` attribute instead:

```
>>> class Foo:
...     def __init__(self):
...         self.name = 'frank'
...         self.id = 7
... 
>>> f = Foo()
>>> type(f)
<type 'instance'>
>>> f.__class__
<class __main__.Foo at 0x107b321f0>
```

For instances of new-style classes (so those classes that do inherit from `object`), `type()` simply returns the `__class__` attribute directly.

Not that it matters here; all you are really doing is looking at attributes, stored directly on the instance itself. Those are stored in the `__dict__` attribute of each instance:

```
>>> f.__dict__
{'name': 'frank', 'id': 7}
```

Method lookups (as well as any other attribute that is defined on the class or its bases), do require that Python looks at the class:

```
>>> f.__init__
<bound method Foo.__init__ of <__main__.Foo instance at 0x107b1d710>>
>>> f
<__main__.Foo instance at 0x107b1d710>
```

For that the `__class__` attribute is used here.

Comment: so what type method checks actually ?

Comment: @shubham: sorry, I am not following you there. At the C code level, old-style instances are just instances of the `instance` type, because the old class system distinguished between types (C structures defined to be used by the Python interpreter) and Python-defined classes. That old world has been replaced by new-style classes where types and Python classes have been unified.

Comment: @shubham: the old-style class instances then are just C structures that hold provide the `__dict__` attribute and the `__class__` reference, among other things.

Comment: @martin thanks for the comparison. so basically each object attributes at its C level are stored in __dict__ (dictionary), and so it really does not matter for whether the object is instance or any other . at least in my case where i am only calling the attributes.

Answer (score 0):

Python performs method calls without looking at the type of the object on which you're calling the method.  It simply checks to see whether the object (*not the class*) contains an attribute which matches the method name, and then checks to see whether that attribute is callable.

In Python, you can take an object of class `X()` where `X()` does not contains a method of `blah()` and add to that object instance a method named `blah()` and call that method -- even though the type knows nothing of such a method.

To see this in action:

```
class C(object): pass

obj1 = C()
obj2 = C()

obj1.double = lambda x: x*2
```

Now, you can call obj1.double():

```
obj1.double("hello")
'hellohello'
```

but not obj2.double():

```
obj2.double("hello")
AttributeError: 'C' object has no attribute 'double'
```

Comment: hey larry what do you mean by 'callable' ? and how do you add method to the object? does it has any analogy to other OOP language like java ?

Comment: No, it is not like Java.  It is like PHP, Javascript and, I think , Perl and Ruby -- a class of languages known as dynamic or "hash table" languages.